# Copy data from one Chrome tab into another Chrome tab

Tags: google-chrome, browser, duplicates, copy

I need to duplicate specific data from a web page in Chrome to another web page in Chrome. More specifically, I need to propagate simple text fields such as first name, last name, city, postal code, etc from a web page that I authored to another web page that I did not author.

The first "source" web page is generated by my Ruby on Rails server and I have 100% control over all aspects of it. The second "destination" web page is supplied by a third party and I have no control over its coding.

Ideally, the user will fill in the source web page, open the destination web page in a different tab and then hit a key to invoke this copy action. The desired fields values will be read from the source web page and duplicated into the desired fields of the destination web page.

It is possible for me to open the destination web page's sign on page by clicking a button on the source web page, but because sign-in is required I probably cannot click a button to open the actual destination page itself. I will probably have to manually sign in and navigate to it.

I've used Ruby, Cucumber, Selenium and app scripts in the past but I don't think those tools are optimal for this.

None of these data are confidential or private. This capability is for in house use only. I have no plans to distribute it.

Is this doable? What approach would you recommend for doing it?

Comment: You can use a Chrome extension to copy information from site A to site B.